# Alias angular 2 route path in browser url

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am working with module and feature loading views using Angular 2, According our requirement it should show feature view according to  selected module.

[image]

Feature view for selected Module1

[image]

Current route path

[image]

So browser url looks like this

[image]
But I need to change it like this

[image]

Please help me to resolve this scenario. Thank You.

Comment: maybe define two routes with `features` and `module1` name?

Comment: module names are dynamically loading and i am using single component to show features of each selected module.

Comment: so do you want to dynamically modify `routes`?

Comment: What's that you have coded? Update is to the post. One line of code is not enough

Comment: yes correct.  i want to add module name in browser url while loading feature component.